# Proof that there are countably many polynomials of degree $n$ with integer coefficients

Tags: polynomials, solution-verification

This question has been [asked before](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1354323/algebraic-numbers-as-roots-of-polynomials-of-degree-n-are-countable), but I wanted to try a different approach than the one linked, and I just wanted to make sure that it worked.

To do this, write out the coefficients as so:
\begin{pmatrix}
   a_{10}&a_{11}&a_{12}&\dots&a_{1n} \\
   a_{20}&a_{21}&a_{22}&\dots&a_{1n} \\
   a_{30}&a_{31}&a_{32}&\dots&a_{1n} \\
   \vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\ddots
\end{pmatrix}

where $a_{ij}$ represents the coefficient to the $x^j$ term in the $i^\text{th}$ polynomial.

We can list these coefficients out like reading a book, left-to-right, followed by top-to-bottom. More specifically, we can create a function $f$ from the natural numbers to these coefficients that map $x$ to $a_{qr}$, where $x=q(n+1)+r$ and $0\leq r<n+1$. This function is injective because a specific $q,r$ pair is associated with a unique natural number $q(n+1)+r$. It is also surjective because given an arbitrary $a_{ij}$, we know that there is a natural number such that $f(x)=a_{ij}$ (specifically $x=i(n+1)+j$).

This means that there are countably many coefficients in ALL polynomials of degree $n$. We can create an injective function from polynomials to the set of all coefficients by mapping each polynomial $P_i$ to its constant term $a_{i0}$, which means that the set of all polynomials of degree $n$ is also countable. Finally, since $A_n$ is a countable union of finite sets (finite number of roots for each polynomial), $A_n$ is countable.

The two main parts I'm not sure about is the bijection I create with coefficients of polynomials and natural numbers, and the existence of an injective function implying that the polynomials have the same cardinality (or less) as the coefficients.

Comment: How are you defining the $i^{th}$ polynomial?  Seems like if you can define that then you've already shown that the collection is countable.

Comment: The number of polynomials of degree $n$ has a direct bijection to the elements of $\mathbb{N}^{n+1}$, and any finite set product of countable sets is countable.

Comment: @lulu that's a good point, I never even considered that.

Comment: paulinho. We make it \mathbb{Z}^{n+1}, OK?